# Getting \setbondstyle undefined error with mol2chemfig

Tags: packages, standalone, chemfig, mol2chemfig

I have observed a Command \setbondstyle undefined error while using the mol2chemfig package with the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=7pt,active,tightpage]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig} 
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\begin{filecontents}{anthracene_aromatic_rings.tex}
\chemfig{                          % 5
              -[:210,0.96]% 1
              -[:270,0.96]% 2
                             (
                     -[:210.9]% 8
                     -[:150.4]% 12
                        -[:90]% 11
                      -[:29.6]% 7
                     -[:329.1]% -> 1
    -[:209.1,0.99,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.28}% (o)
                             )
                             (
       -[:30,0.96,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.25}% (o)
                             )
              -[:330,0.96]% 6
               -[:30,0.96]% 4
               -[:90,0.96]% 3
                             (
                  -[:150,0.96]% -> 5
                             )
                  -[:30.9]% 9
                             (
    -[:270.2,0.99,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.29}% (o)
                             )
                 -[:330.4]% 13
                   -[:270]% 14
                 -[:209.6]% 10
                             (
                     -[:149.1]% -> 4
                             )
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
\chemfig{           H% 2
    -[:210]% 1
              (
        -[:210]H% 3
              )
              (
        -[:300]H% 5
              )
    -[:120]H% 4
}
\end{filecontents}


% sans serif font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

% define formulae
\def\anthracene{\mathrm{C_{14}H_{10}}}
\def\methane{\mathrm{CH_{4}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[]{lp{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Structure}\\
\midrule%
%$\methane$ & \begin{minipage}{1cm} \input{methane.tex} \end{minipage} \\ [2mm]%
$\anthracene$ & \begin{minipage}{1cm} \input{anthracene_aromatic_rings.tex} \end{minipage} \\ [2mm]%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

A successful compile is observed if one comments `\usepackage{mol2chemfig}` and the line in the table for anthracene (which calls some of the macros contained in `mol2chemfig`).

I verified my `chemfig` package installation (managed through console) and removed a copy of `chemfig.sty` that was in my texmf tree.

For installation of `mol2chemfig`, I simply downloaded the `mol2chemfig.sty` and placed it in my texmf tree manually, doing FNDB after depositing files.

Could there be an accessory file that I do not have in which `\setbondstyle` is defined?

Perhaps I should be calling a supplementary package?

Comment: \setbondstyle is a deprecated chemfig command but mol2chemfig stores the bondstyle in a tikz key, so this is going to break. Suggest you contact the mol2chemfig author or rewrite your code to avoid using mol2chemfig.

Comment: Would using the version of chemfig that mol2chemfig was developed with be a solution?

Comment: @JohnChris - yes, that should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the mol2chemfig author and apologize for not having fixed this yet, even though it was pointed out to me a while ago. As a quick fix, you can just comment out or delete the entire block

```
\let\mcf@setbondstyle\setbondstyle
\renewcommand{\setbondstyle}[1]{%
    \mcf@setbondstyle{#1}%
    \tikzset{mcfbond/.style={#1}}%
}
```

inside `mol2chemfig.sty`.

Edit: OK, so there are additional problems here that I cannot solve. In the newer versions of `chemfig`, the former `\CF@atom@sep` and `\CF@cycle@inraduiscoeff` have been replaced with `\CF_atomsep` and `\CF_cycleradiuscoeff`, but simply making those substitutions in `mol2fchemfig` does not work. There may be some catcode trickery involved that is beyond me. I will ask the `chemfig` author for help with this and hopefully have an update soon. In the meantime, the only solution seems to be to use an ancient version of `chemfig`.

Second edit: I just tested this on my system, and it worked.

1) I downloaded the old version (1.2d) of `chemfig.tex` which I posted at https://pastebin.com/uJWRDXuj earlier and saved it as `cf-pastebin.tex` into an empty directory.

2) Into the same directory, I saved a copy of `mol2chemfig.sty` under the name `mol2chemfigfix.sty`. I edited the first couple of lines of that file to use `cf-pastebin.tex` directly:

```
% auxiliary package for mol2chemfig
\ProvidesPackage{mol2chemfigfix} % use the modified mol2chemfig package

\RequirePackage{xcolor, twoopt, ifmtarg, tikz} % load tikz as a prereq for chemfig
\input{cf-pastebin.tex}  % load this directly, don't mess with chemfig.sty

\def\printatom#1{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}% \printatom pour LaTeX.
\expandafter\def\csname CF\string_begintikzpicture\endcsname{\begin{tikzpicture}}%
\expandafter\def\csname CF\string_endtikzpicture\endcsname{\end{tikzpicture}}%

\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
```

I then used the following MWE (also saved into the same directory):

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mol2chemfigfix} 

% minimal example that exercises all \CF@... macros used by mol2chemfig

\begin{document}
\chemfig{
              -[:210,0.96]% 1
              -[:270,0.96]% 2
                             (
                     -[:210.9]% 8
                     -[:150.4](-[:210]
                               -[:150,,,,drhs]
                              )
                        -[:90]% 11
                      -[:29.6]% 7
                     -[:329.1]% -> 1
    -[:209.1,0.99,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.28}% (o)
                             )
}
\end{document}
```

This gives no errors and produces the expected output. Since it does not invoke `chemfig.sty` at all, I hope this will work for you also.

Comment: Thanks!  On trying this and then attempting to compile the mwe above I'm seeing: `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \CF@atom@sep                       *1.28*0.66667*\CF@cycle@inraduiscoeff`.  The `\mcfcringle` definition code is presenting an issue.

Comment: @JohnChris - please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Palmer.  How ancient?  Are you able to provide a version number or url?

Comment: @JohnChris - On my system, I have  chemfig v1.2d, which works. I just posted the content of that version of `chemfig.tex` to https://pastebin.com/uJWRDXuj . Note that `chemfig.sty` is just a hook to load `chemfig.tex`, which contains the actual package code. If you arrange for `chemfig.sty` to find the old version of `chemfig.tex`, it should work.

Comment: I placed the v1.2d `chemfig.tex` at `...\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\chemfig` on my system, changing the filename of the up to date file so that it would not be found.  When I compile the mwe I get: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \CFname .3 \ProvidesPackage\CFname [\CFdate\space v\CFver\space Draw molecule with a...`

Comment: @JohnChris - please see updated answer.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Upvote your answer. But help you to contibuite for this site: https://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig/home. Yet I have not understood as export a draw in LaTeX. It is very complicated to draw a chemical scheme.

Comment: @Sebastiano - I am not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer If you're also participating in the construction of the online tool that I have given you.

Comment: Thanks again!  I can confirm that the proposed solution works.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Is there any chance of a new version of `mol2chemfig.sty` solving this without the need for this sort of hacking appearing soon?

Comment: My mistake. In fact there seem to be one: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/mol2chemfig/latex

Comment: @jonalv - yes, I uploaded an update a couple of days ago - I hope it will work now, but there are several versions of chemfig floating around, so if you experience any incompatibilities,  please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with the `chemfig` and `mol2chemfig` packages. When I try to set the bond length using the statement `\setatomsep{2.25 em}` I get the following error message:

```
`Undefined control sequence. \setatomsep`.
```

I tried to fix the problem following the steps provided by @Michel Palmer, but I did not manage to solve the problem: the MWE gives a lot of errors, the first one is `Undefined control sequence`. So, I am wondering, in which directory do I have to save files `cf-pastebin.tex`, `mol2chemfigfix.sty`? Maybe I did not place those files in the right directory...