# Undefined control sequence \mcfbelow when using chemfig in LaTeX

Tags: errors, chemfig, chemistry

I came across an error when trying to incorporate a simple chemfig diagram in a document. Here is a minimal working example (the code for the diagram was generated using [mol2chemfig](https://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig/home)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{
              O% 2
       =[:330]\mcfbelow{C}{H}% 1
    -[:30,,,1]OH% 3
}
\end{document}
```

The error is 'Undefined control sequence: \mcfbelow'.

This compiles, producing the following diagram, which is not what I want.

[image]

What is intended is this, with the hydrogen directly below the carbon and the OH bonded directly to the carbon:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: install the mol2chemfig package from CTAN and add \usepackage{mol2chemfig} to the preamble.

Comment: I am getting `Command \setbondstyle undefined.` error so the above comment is not working. The same error has been reported previously: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502610/]. I suggest reporting to the `mol2chemfig` author. There has been a series of upgrades to `chemfig` over the past 12 months so they may not be playing nicely together.

Comment: @Ross Thanks very much, that works.