# Catchfile and complex chemfig symbols

Tags: chemfig, catchfile, mol2chemfig

An excellent suggestion for a way to call `chemfig` symbols stored in individual files from a common library was put forth [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502677/input-inside-chemfig).  I have tested the solution with a variety of relatively simple compounds / chemfig symbols.  [This issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556948/issue-with-mol2chemfig-and-moderately-complex-structural-formula) shows a case where the proposed solution produces an error.

The issue is suspected to reside somewhere in the file writing and cat code handling.

Any suggestions on tweaks enabling the code to handle more complex compounds are greatly appreciated.

I have included the mwe here:

```
\documentclass[english,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}%


\tikzset{
  % #1 = left, #2 = lower, #3 = right, #4 = upper
  enlarge bounding box by/.style n args={4}{
    execute at end picture={
      \path ([shift={(-#1, -#2)}]current bounding box.south west) --
            ([shift={(#3, #4)}]current bounding box.north east);
    }
  }
}

% chemfigdo
\newcommand{\chemfigdo}[2]{\chemfig[#2]{#1}}%

% chemfiginput
\newcommand{\chemfiginput}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\chemfiginputtemp}{#2}{\csname CF_sanitizecatcode\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\chemfigdo\expandafter{\chemfiginputtemp}{#1}%
}%

% create new command for tikzpicture call
\newcommand\callchemfigsymbol[1]{%
  \chemfiginput[
      atom style={scale=\chemfigscale},
      atom sep=\chemfigatomsep,
      chemfig style={
        enlarge bounding box by={\chemfigborder}{\chemfigborder}{\chemfigborder}{\chemfigborder},
        baseline=(current bounding box.center),
        color=\chemfigcolor,
        line width=\chemfiglinewidth
      }
    ]{#1}%
}


\begin{filecontents}{s_adenosyl_l_methionine.tex}
                   O% 6
           =[:95.9]% 26
                      (
               -[:35.9]O% 5
         -[:335.9,0.62]H% 50
                      )
          -[:155.9]% 24
                      (
              <:[:95.9]N% 10
                          (
             -[:155.9,0.62]H% 46
                          )
          -[:35.9,0.62]H% 45
                      )
                      (
         -[:155.9,0.62]H% 44
                      )
          -[:215.9]% 21
                      (
         -[:235.9,0.62]H% 39
                      )
                      (
         -[:315.9,0.62]H% 40
                      )
          -[:155.9]% 18
                      (
          -[:55.9,0.62]H% 34
                      )
                      (
         -[:135.9,0.62]H% 35
                      )
          -[:215.9]\mcfabove{S}{_{\mcfplus}}% 1
                      (
              -[:275.9]% 22
                          (
             -[:275.9,0.62]H% 42
                          )
                          (
               -[:5.9,0.62]H% 43
                          )
         -[:185.9,0.62]H% 41
                      )
          -[:155.9]% 17
                      (
          -[:55.9,0.62]H% 32
                      )
                      (
         -[:135.9,0.62]H% 33
                      )
          >[:215.9]% 13
                      (
         -[:332.9,0.62]H% 28
                      )
          -[:269.9]O% 2
          -[:197.9]% 16
                      (
              -[:125.9]% 15
                          (
                   -[:53.9]% 14
                              (
                      -[:341.9]% -> 13
                              )
                              (
                  -[:44.9,0.62]H% 29
                              )
                 <:[:107.9]O% 3
              -[:47.9,0.62]H% 36
                          )
                          (
             -[:116.9,0.62]H% 30
                          )
             <:[:179.9]O% 4
         -[:119.9,0.62]H% 37
                      )
                      (
         -[:314.9,0.62]H% 31
                      )
          <[:251.9]N% 7
    -[:197.8,0.994]% 19
           =^[:150]N% 9
            -[:210]% 27
                      (
           -[:150,0.62]H% 47
                      )
           =^[:270]N% 11
            -[:330]% 25
                      (
                -[:270]N% 12
                          (
               -[:330,0.62]H% 49
                          )
           -[:210,0.62]H% 48
                      )
            =^[:30]% 23
                      (
                 -[:90]% -> 19
                      )
    -[:342.2,0.994]N% 8
      =^[:54,0.994]% 20
                      (
          -[:126,0.994]\phantom{N}% -> 7
                      )
           -[,0.62]H% 38
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
           H% 2
     -[:270]C% 1
              (
        -[:200]H% 4
              )
              (
         <[:310]H% 5
              )
    <:[:350]H% 3
\end{filecontents}


% define the atom sep
\newlength{\chemfigatomsep}%
\setlength{\chemfigatomsep}{2.75em}%

% define the line width
\newlength{\chemfiglinewidth}%
\setlength{\chemfiglinewidth}{0.75pt}%

% define the scale
\def\chemfigscale{1}

% define the color
\def\chemfigcolor{blue!40!black}

% define separation length
\newlength{\chemfigborder}
\setlength{\chemfigborder}{1mm}



\begin{document}

%\callchemfigsymbol{s_adenosyl_l_methionine.tex}% when I uncomment this, I observe error
\callchemfigsymbol{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}% this works fine

\end{document}
```

Comment: What error? If I download `mol2chemfig` (which is not available in TeX LIve), I get no error when uncommenting the first `\callchemfigsymbol` line.

Comment: My apologies, I am able to compile.  I must have had an older version of `mol2chemfig`